# How to know if all elements inside the ARRAY of THREAD with dynamic size is finished in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

If I have an array of thread with dynamic size, how will I be able to determine if all threads inside that array is already finished? I am also planning to create a FUNCTION that will trigger another thread to start when all these threads in the array is finished.
Thank you.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you can use `Thread`'s `isAlive()` method to determine if a thread is still alive.

Comment: Have you looked at `wait()` `notify()` `notifyAll()` ?

Answer (score 1):

> If I have an array of thread with dynamic size, how will I be able to determine if all threads inside that array is already finished?

I'd use an `ExecutorService` thread-pool which you can then query to see if the jobs have been fully processed.  A cached thread pool will fork a thread for each of the `Runnable`s (or `Callable`s) you submit to it.  You can also used a fix thread pool with a fixed number of threads running the submitted jobs.  You then don't have to keep your own array of threads, etc..

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadPool.submit(myRunnable);
...
// after you submit the last job, you shut it down
threadPool.shutdown();
// then we can wait for the pool to finish
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean areAllThreadsTerminated(Collection<Thread> threadList) {
    for (Thread thread : threadList)
        if (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

as an option

```
public static boolean areAllThreadsFinished(Collection<Thread> threadList) {
        for (Thread thread : threadList)
            if (thread.isAlive())
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

if you want to wait in a main thread:

```
    //wait in the main thread
    try {
        while (!areAllThreadsFinished(threadList)) {
            threadList.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

at the end on each thread

```
threadList.notify();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Sash, 
Can I ask what do you mean by "at the end on each thread", does it mean, inside the run method in a class which implements a runnable interface?

Should I put the areAllThreadsFinished function inside a Thread or an inner class which implements a runnable interface?
I forgot to tell it that the main thread is a GUI/Swing JFrame. Thank you.

Comment: ok, if you are running in a GUI you should not stop and wait, just put areAllThreadsFinished in a GUI thread, without wait

Comment: I don't know what are threads doing, but of you are doing something with a network, or long calculation there are a lot of standart solutuins, google for example "GUI long calculation example java thread". Or maybe you need a progress bar. There is also SwingWorker class for a Swing. There are a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

A thread can be in one of the following states:

- **NEW** - A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- **RUNNABLE** - A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- **BLOCKED** - A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
- **WAITING** - A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- **TIMED_WAITING** - A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
- **TERMINATED**
  A thread that has exited is in this state.
  A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states.

Verify `Thread.getState()` is `TERMINATED` using something similar below;

```
if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED){ 
 // thread completed its job
}
```

When the `run()` method ends, then a `Thread` will go to the `TERMINATED`state.

In your particular use case, you can loop through an array to verify that all threads are terminated then create another thread to do the next task per your requirement.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response @fabfas. I'm new to threading. I would just like to ask if it is a good thing or a necessary thing to do the following in using thread

If I have a class implementing a Runnable interface with run()
public class A implements Runnable(){
   run(){
     // do something
   }
}

then in main thread
i have 
Thread thread = new Thread(new A())
thread.start()
or should I just instantiate an A object without a thread. Please note that the main thread is a Swing/JFrame class. Thank you.

Comment: @James-AndrewSarmiento It really depends what kinda behaviour object A is encapsulating. For example, if object A suppose to do a long running job then best to create a thread otherwise Swing/JFrame screen will be unresponsive. If user expect an instant response then there is no need to create a thread.

Comment: @James-AndrewSarmiento Since you are working on a Swing application, I suggest you take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html. Note the last sentence in the class doc: "Because SwingWorker implements Runnable, a SwingWorker can be submitted to an Executor for execution." There are several implementations of such Executors (look at ThreadPoolExecutor for example). This will allow you to decouple the submission of jobs from the number of threads that execute the jobs.